# Which elements I should use for it?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

I'm just starting to get acquainted with Android Studio and I want to make a menu in my application approximately as shown in the photo. What elements should I use for this? 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/NzSG1.png

Comment: viewpager and tablayout

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are just starting with the android studio, you can design the layout using a **Relative/Linear layout**. Try to divide the whole layout into pieces like dividing it into rows and working row by row.

Let say you want to design those items in the second row then you can approach it as

1. A parent Linear layout for the row(horizontal orientation) which include three children linear layouts(one for each item details)
2. Each child layout can be oriented as vertical containing 3 views (one for item picture, one for item name, and last for item detail)

Like this, you have to first decide which way you want to design your app.

Start small and evolve gradually.

For more details on components to use you can refer the following link.

[Material Design Components](https://material.io/guidelines/components/#)

I hope this will be useful to get you started.